# calculate length and area of polygon

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a script that computes the length and area of a polygon using ginput. So no matter how many points I choose, I should get the area and length displayed. I have created two functions, one for calculating the area and one calculating the length.

Length:

```
function L=polylen(x,y)
    n=length(x);
    L=0;
for i=1:n-1
    L=L+sqrt((x(i+1)-x(i))^2+(y(i+1)-y(i))^2);
end
```

Area:

```
function A=polyarea(x,y)
    n=length(x);
    A=0;
for i=1:n-1
    A=A+(x(i+1)+x(i))*(y(i+1)-y(i));
end
A=abs(A)/2;
```

My script for plotting and closing the polygon is

```
clf
axis([0 1 0 1]), hold on
[x,y]=ginput(1);
plot(x,y,'o')
xpol=x;
ypol=y;
while 1 
    [x,y,knapp]=ginput(1);
    if knapp~=1
        break
    end
    xpol=[xpol;x];
    ypol=[ypol;y];
    plot(xpol(end-1:end),ypol(end-1:end),'o-')
end
xpol=[xpol;xpol(1)];
    ypol=[ypol;ypol(1)];
    plot(xpol(end-1:end),ypol(end-1:end),'o-')
    hold off
```

How can I now call on these functions and incorporate them in my script so that they can compute these two values?

Answer (score 1):

Copying it straight from the [manual](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html), there are a few ways to define a function, the most commom :

1. [**File**](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html)

   *Save this in a separated file with name equal to the name of the function, in the example: **average.m***

   ```
   function y = average(x)
   if ~isvector(x)
       error('Input must be a vector')
   end
   y = sum(x)/length(x); 
   end
   ```
2. [**Local**](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) (required matlab 2016b or higher)

   *Just save it at the end of your script*

   ```
   % Add it as the last part of your script.       
   function y = myIntegrand(x)
   y = sin(x).^3;
   end
   ```
3. [**Anonymous**](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) (works in old matlabs)

   *Just save it in the script, and call it in the next lines.*

   ```
   %add to your script
   myfunction = @(x,y) (x^2 + y^2 + x*y);
   ```

And in all the cases, just call the function as you call any other function. For instance in you case if you want to *call it every step and write it in the graph*, you can do it in this way:

```
clf
axis([0 1 0 1]), hold on
[x,y]=ginput(1);
plot(x,y,'o')
xpol=x;
ypol=y;
while 1 
    [x,y,knapp]=ginput(1);
    if knapp~=1
        break
    end
    xpol=[xpol;x];
    ypol=[ypol;y];
    plot(xpol(end-1:end),ypol(end-1:end),'o-')

    if numel(xpol)>2
        mylen=polylen(xpol,ypol);
        myarea=polyarea(xpol,ypol);
        text(0.1,0.1,['len=',num2str(mylen)],'backgroundcolor',[1 1 1])
        text(0.1,0.9,['area=',num2str(myarea)],'backgroundcolor',[1 1 1])
    elseif numel(xpol)>1
        mylen=polylen(xpol,ypol);
        text(0.1,0.1,['len=',num2str(mylen)],'backgroundcolor',[1 1 1])
    end


end
xpol=[xpol;xpol(1)];
ypol=[ypol;ypol(1)];
plot(xpol(end-1:end),ypol(end-1:end),'o-')
if numel(xpol)>2
        mylen=polylen(xpol,ypol);
        myarea=polyarea(xpol,ypol);
        text(0.1,0.1,['len=',num2str(mylen)],'backgroundcolor',[1 1 1])
        text(0.1,0.9,['area=',num2str(myarea)],'backgroundcolor',[1 1 1])
elseif numel(xpol)>1
        mylen=polylen(xpol,ypol);
        text(0.1,0.1,['len=',num2str(mylen)],'backgroundcolor',[1 1 1])
end
hold off
```

In this case, the functions are in a separated .m file.

Notice that i'm basically overwriting the text every time a new point is plotted. It is not the most elegant solution, but it is the first one that i thought.

The `if` statements can be neglected in case you don't mind the error output, it stills work without it.

Comment: As you can see in my posts, the functions are already defined. Now in the third script, I want it to use these functions to calculate area and length of the polygons.

Comment: I added it in my way to make it a text in the plot. You could use the output in prompt or any other method.